# "Invalid left-hand side in assignment" on style property assignment

Tags: javascript, operator-precedence

error unveils when this line is evaluated:

```js
color && el.style.color = color;
```

what's going on? are DOM level 2 properties now a "read-only"?

Comment: last line seems to be creating an issue http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/98SCK/

Comment: Please use `if(color)` instead of `color &&`. Making things short is fine, but not if it reduces readability or even introduces problems. Edit: +1 since you realized that `if` is better on your own!

Comment: @ThiefMaster, thanks, but that's not the issue at hand.

Comment: @ThiefMaster - apparently, that was exactly the issue :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is [precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), you need parens:

```
function log(msg, color) {
    var el = document.createElement('p');
    el.innerText = msg;
    document.getElementById('log').appendChild(el);
    color && (el.style.color = color);
}
```

`&&` has higher precedence than `=` and so without the parens, you end up trying to assign to an expression (e.g., it effectively reads `(color && el.style.color) = color;`), which of course you cannot do.

Comment: thanks, i'd like to add to that: one could also put the assignment into a closure to solve this, tho not preferred (excessive use of closures will strain the call hierarchy mechanism).

Comment: @EliranMalka: LOL, yes, you could do that. Fairly expensive form of parentheses. Or of course you could just use `if`, as you're no longer saving those two characters... ;-)

Comment: nice, i think i'd prefer the old `if`... someone is gonna have to read this sometime :)  thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Mark Linus, though you can also rewrite your code to

```js
color && (el.style.color = color)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the "**?.**" optional chain operator, you have to remove it.

Example:

```
//wrong
el?.style?.color = color;


//ok
el.style.color = color;
```

Comment: thanx, but i wasn't; that is a bit of an old question by now :)

Comment: Yes but the same error could appear for different reasons, it is good to have a few solutions "documented" here for new users :)

Comment: sure thing !  :)